# NPM error on peer dependencies on react project

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm trying to build my react app and I'm getting this warning on NPM dependencies.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: eh-frontend@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.6" from @chakra-ui/icons@1.1.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@chakra-ui/icons
npm ERR!     @chakra-ui/icons@"^1.1.7" from the root project
npm ERR!   2 more (@emotion/react, @emotion/styled)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@">=18" from @chakra-ui/system@2.3.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@chakra-ui/system
npm ERR!   peer @chakra-ui/system@">=1.0.0" from @chakra-ui/icons@1.1.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@chakra-ui/icons
npm ERR!     @chakra-ui/icons@"^1.1.7" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-08T16_29_29_291Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: Removing the chakra-ui/icons@1.1.7 library help to resolved the issue.